# How can I change UITableView label textColor twice in animations?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to highlight the text in a table view to indicate that it has been copied. I change it first to a different colour then back to black in the animation code. But when I run it, it gets stuck after the first change. I have uses UIColor.green for testing. After this code runs, the colour remains green.

Can anyone see what is wrong with this?

```
let allCells: ((UITableViewCell) -> Void) -> Void = { handler in
    if let paths = self.savedTempTable.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
        paths.compactMap { self.savedTempTable.cellForRow(at: $0) }.forEach { cell in
            handler(cell)
        }
        self.savedTempTable.reloadRows(at: paths, with: .none)
    }
}

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
               animations: { allCells { cell in cell.textLabel?.textColor = .green } },
               completion: { _ in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { allCells { cell in cell.textLabel?.textColor = .black } } )
}
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To animate `textColor`, you need to use [transition(with:duration:options:animations:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622574-transition) instead.

```
for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
  UIView.transition(with: cell, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .green
  }) { (_) in
    UIView.transition(with: cell, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
      cell.textLabel?.textColor = .black
    }, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Result

[image: enter link description here]

For more detail, you can check my sample

https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/animate-label-text-color

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out,  but the trouble is, I never see font turn green. It just stays the same. This is in the simulator on an iPhone X

Comment: As I know, it should work. For more detail, I added a sample project. You can check it. Make sure you call it on main queue.

Comment: I tried your app, and it worked, every time I clicked on the button. Thanks for going to that effort.

But my app is still not working. It may have something to do with UITableView.

Comment: @MarkAurelius I tried it with UITableView and it works too. I think there is a problem with `allCells`. You should try to animate visible cells using a for loop. Maybe it will work.

Comment: Hmm. What code did you use to call it on a cell?
I don't think the allCells function is the problem. I added this code right before handle(cell) and it gets called for each cell: print("Handling", cell.textLabel?.text ?? "?")

Comment: Did you try to use the code on my answer. I updated it with for loop

Comment: Hey! That did it !! ??
I changed it slightly to savedTempTable.visibleCells.forEach { cell in ... Thanks for hanging in there.

Comment: You must have been right that there was a problem in the allCells function. But with the visibleCells property it is not needed. Your way, @trungduc was best.